# Adding <img> before first child of wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using the `wp_nav_menu` function within Wordpress, I am trying to add in a logo  before the first child of the `<ul>` to basically achieve the same effect as how many sites have a logo on the left within the navigation bar itself, i.e. https://trello.com/.

How can I best go about achieving this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Lloyd

Comment: i think you can modify the header file `themes/<theme-name>/header.php` to add a logo element.

Comment: I have tried this method, by slotting in a `<div>` or an `<img>` before or after the PHP but this doesn't seem to work properly for me.

Comment: can you show the code and CSS for that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_new_menu_item', 10, 2);
function add_new_menu_item( $nav, $args ) {
    $newmenuitem = "<li class='home-link'><img src='PATH_TO_YOUR_LOGO'/></li>";
    $nav = $newmenuitem.$nav;
    return $nav;
}
```

If you want to add the logo only when the menu is "primary", use this:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_new_menu_item', 10, 2);
function add_new_menu_item( $nav, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
    $newmenuitem = "<li class='home-link'><img src='PATH_TO_YOUR_LOGO'/></li>";
    $nav = $newmenuitem.$nav;
    return $nav;
}
```